# avoid repetitions in elastic search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the data below i want to avoid Duplicate practice area names in result How can Avoid Duplicates in my Elastic Search Result. Please Send me to Solutions.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_index] => vendors
            [_type] => practiceareas
            [_id] => 240
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [practice_area_id] => 237
                    [id] => 240
                    [practice_area_name] => Anemia
                    [practice_area_image] => 
                    [created_date] => 2016-07-04 14:51:46
                    [status] => 1
                    [industry_id] => 9
                    [category_id] => 14
                    [vendors_count] => 26
                    [services_count] => 0
                    [products_count] => 0
                )

            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_index] => vendors
            [_type] => practiceareas
            [_id] => 582
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [practice_area_id] => 364
                    [id] => 582
                    [practice_area_name] => Joint Pains
                    [practice_area_image] => 
                    [created_date] => 2016-07-04 14:51:47
                    [status] => 1
                    [industry_id] => 9
                    [category_id] => 12
                    [vendors_count] => 26
                    [services_count] => 0
                    [products_count] => 0
                )

            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [_index] => vendors
            [_type] => practiceareas
            [_id] => 1315
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [practice_area_id] => 237
                    [id] => 1315
                    [practice_area_name] => Anemia
                    [practice_area_image] => 
                    [created_date] => 2016-07-04 14:51:46
                    [status] => 1
                    [industry_id] => 9
                    [category_id] => 15
                    [vendors_count] => 26
                    [services_count] => 0
                    [products_count] => 0
                )

            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26
                )

        )
)
```

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to use [Field Collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html) to present search results grouped by a particular field. Grouping by name implies the need for a terms aggregation.

To be able to group on the 'practice_area_name', the field should be available in its original `not_analyzed` form. Otherwise, you should group on 'practice_area_id' to avoid `not_analyzed` field.

```
"aggs": {
    "vendors": {
      "terms": {
        "field":   "practice_area_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dedup_docs": { "top_hits": { "size": 1 }}  
      }
    }
  }
```

Note : The top_score aggregation orders the terms in the users aggregation by the top-scoring document in each bucket.

Comment: When adding Above Code This Error Find :
                            [reason] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => script_exception
                                    [reason] => scripts of type [inline], operation [aggs] and lang [groovy] are disabled

Comment: [reason] => scripts of type [inline], operation [aggs] and lang [groovy] are disabled
                        )

Comment: scripting is disabled by default in elasticsearch. I am updating my answer to remove scripting for score

Comment: but i am getting again duplicate Records

Comment: But getting only 10 Records in "aggregations" How can can get 20 records minimum

Comment: what do u mean by 'minimum 20' ? Do you want to fetch all records or just 20 or anything else ? There is a size param https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size

Comment: all duplicates records are fetch and placed at "hits" section but without duplicates records fetch and placed in "aggregations" section but it shows only 10 Records minimum how can increase record count in "aggregations" section

Comment: My Query Is Following :

{"from":0,"size":50,"sort":[{"vendors_count":"desc"}],"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":[]}}},"aggs":{"vendors":{"terms":{"field":"practice_area_name"},"aggs":{"dedup_docs":{"top_hits":{"size":1}}}}}}

Comment: i am adding load more practiceareas when i Click on load more button then show  remaining Records How i can use please send me to solition

Comment: The feature for pagination in aggregation is not implemented yet. You could use the combination on size and exclude feature in facet. There is a bug logged for the same : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915